# Why Chrome detects my new tab as an Ad ? - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, adblock

I have a maybe strange question but still a little bit annoying .
In our interface we have created an user interaction by simply clicking a button and previewing an PDF file on a new tab . Everything is working fine , but if you have you Chrome AdBlocker extension activated it automatically triggers and it doesn't allow to the user to preview his document . It is a little bit annoying , because i had to display a big message for each user in order to have a properly working app to disable their AdBlocker extensions . So i ask myself is there a way to prevent this scenario? [image: chrome]

```
  const postHeader = {
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Accept': 'application/pdf',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
        }
    };

    // Prepare request to the BE body
    const postBody = {
        customerNumber,
        tenant
    };

    if (!isNaN(pdfID)) {

        // Firing the request to the BE
        axios.post(serverUrl + '/api/user/bill/' + pdfID, postBody, postHeader)

            .then((response) => {
                // If there is blob data with the PDF, we show it
                if (response.data.byteLength > 0) {
                    // We create a file from the blob
                    const file = new Blob([response.data], {
                        type: 'application/pdf'
                    });

                    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, "output.pdf");
                    } else {
                        const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                        window.open(objectUrl);
                        console.log(objectUrl)
                    }
```

Comment: Please share the code you have implemented to open the PDF

Comment: @Lennholm it is updated !

Comment: Has nothing about being an ad. It is the fact you are opening up the pop up window asynchronously. A window has to open up with the user action, there can not be a delay. So option is open the window first with a loading message or why even use an Ajax call and just post a form to a new window. Just add the check that the save code is supported before you do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common pop-up blocking strategy in browsers is to require any new window/tab to be opened as a direct result of a user interaction. Since your click event handler initiates an asynchronous process and you don't open the new window until it has resolved, this means that the browser will block it because too much time has elapsed between the user interaction and `window.open()`.

The easiest way to fix this is simply to open the window before you start reading the data and then write to it once you have the data ready. Something like this should work:

```
if (!isNaN(pdfID)) {

    const pdfWindow = window.open('about:blank');

    // Firing the request to the BE
    axios.post(serverUrl + '/api/user/bill/' + pdfID, postBody, postHeader)

        .then((response) => {
            // If there is blob data with the PDF, we show it
            if (response.data.byteLength > 0) {
                // We create a file from the blob
                const file = new Blob([response.data], {
                    type: 'application/pdf'
                });

                const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);

                pdfWindow.document.location.href = objectUrl;
```

You can also use a static page as placeholder instead of `about:blank`, e.g. a page that just displays a message, like `Loading...`.

I'm not sure how to handle that `window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob` thing as I'm not at all familiar with it.

Comment: An even better alternative might be to just do the post request that loads the PDF in the new window, instead of doing an ajax request, converting the result to a blob, and then navigating there.

Comment: @Lenholm thank you for the answer , but i have tried this method already . And the problem persist to be there .

Comment: @PandaMastr You mean it doesn't open a new window even if you put `window.open()` at the top of your click event handler?

Comment: @Lennholm the behaivoiour is the same . It tries to open a new window but is prevented by the AdBlocker .

Comment: @PandaMastr Maybe you have configured your browser to block all pop-ups, then it wouldn't work anyway. I'm pretty sure the default config in all browsers is to allow pop-ups that are directly opened by a user interaction. Are you applying your event handlers natively or are you using some framework or library with its own event system (like React)? It could be that those event handlers then become indirect.